# Checkbox delete several jobs/rows

Tags: php

Hi: I have a legacy php4 app that we still have several clients using.
one client wants to have a feature added to a listing page that will allow them to select several jobs and then delete those selected in one click.

I want to add a column to the left of the current first column that contains a check-box user selects as many check-boxes as he wants, then clicks delete and those 5, 8, 20 are deleted, actually archived in this case.

so I basically want similar functionality that's in gmail applied in this code base.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Here is the code that spits out the job listing page**

```
function getRequest(rn)
{
    document.forms.intake.R_NUMBER.value=rn;
    goTo('WHOLEBRIEF','display');
}

function archiveRequest(rn)
{
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this request?'))
    {
        document.forms.intake.R_NUMBER.value=rn;
        goTo('LIST','remove');
    }
}

</script>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="include/table.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="include/jquery.js"></SCRIPT>
<style type="text/css">
th.table-sortable {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-image:url("/images/sortable.gif");
    background-position:center left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left:12px;
}
th.table-sorted-asc {
    background-image:url("/images/sorted_up.gif");
    background-position:center left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
th.table-sorted-desc {
    background-image:url("/images/sorted_down.gif");
    background-position:center left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
tr.alternates {
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
}
</style>
<input type="hidden" name="JOB_NUMBER">
 <center>
<table class="jobs" width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<label>Show All Jobs</label>

<table width="1150" style="border: 1px solid #660099;" class="jobs sort01 table-autosort table-autofilter table-stripeclass:alternate table-filtered-rowcount:t1filtercount">
<thead>
<tr bgcolor="#cccccc" align="center">
<th width="50"  class="table-sortable:numeric"><label>Number</label></td>
<th width="200" class="table-filterable table-sortable:default"><label>Requested By</label></td>
<th width="200" class="table-sortable:default"><label>Project Name</label></td>
<th width="200" class="table-filterable table-sortable:default"><label>Project Category</label></td>
<th width="200" class="table-filterable table-sortable:default"><label>Job Type</label></td>  
<th width="150" class="table-sortable:date"><label>Date Submitted</label></td>
<th width="150" class="table-sortable:date"><label>Due Date</label></td>
<th width="100" class="table-filterable table-sortable:default"><label>Status</label></td>
<th width="20">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<?

$i=0;
if(is_array($R)):
foreach ($R as $key=>$val):?>
<tr bgcolor="<?=getBGC($i)?>">
<td><a href="#" onclick="getReqs('<?=$R[$key]['JOB_NUMBER']?>');return false;"><?=$key?></a></td>
<td><?=$R[$key]['ANSWER']['Q_2']?></td><!--requestor name-->
<td><?=$R[$key]['ANSWER']['Q_5']?></td><!--project name-->
<td><?=$R[$key]['ANSWER']['Q_4']?></td><!--project category-->
<td><?=$R[$key]['ANSWER']['Q_25']?></td><!--job specs-->
<td align="center"><?=formatDate($R[$key]['R_DATE_SUBMITTED'],'y-m-d','m/d/y')?></td>
<td  align="center"><?=$R[$key]['ANSWER']['Q_22']?></td><!--due Date-->

<td  align="center"><?=lookupChange($R[$key]['R_STATUS'])?></td>
<td width="20">
    <?if($tKey):?>
       <a href="#" onclick="archiveRequest('<?=$R[$key]['JOB_NUMBER']?>');return false"><img src="images/b_close.gif" border="0"></a>
    <?endif;?>
    </td>
</tr>

<?$i++;endforeach;endif;?>
</table>  
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

</table>    </center>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broad strokes:
Add a checkbox with a name ending in []. When it's submitted you will be able to loop through the multiple results and process each one.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="archive[]" value="<?=$R[$key]['JOB_NUMBER']?>" />
```

Submit those values using a form (looks like you can just wrap your table in a form).

On the server side, you can loop through the array of results like so:

```
if(!empty($_POST['archive'])) {
    foreach($_POST['archive'] as $archiveId) {
        echo $archiveId;
        // archive the values specified
    }
}
```